# Can't Access Image URL on Single Page

Tags: templating, singles

I have the 404 page setup as a single in sections under `page404`.

I have a `postImage` field that pulls images from assets.  It is assigned to the `page404` field layout and it is assigned in the entry.

I tried the this template approach:

```
{% set notFound = craft.entries.section('page404') %}
<img src="{{ notFound.postImage.first().url }}" width="800" height="800" alt="">
```

but I keep getting the following error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("url") on a null variable

***What am I doing wrong, and how should it be template?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left off the `.first()`.

```
{% set notFound = craft.entries.section('page404').first() %}
```

Without that, the Element Criteria Model will default to `.find()`.

- `first` - Returns a single Entry Model.
- `find` - Returns an array of Entry Models.

**It doesn't matter this this is a Single section!** All Element Criteria Models have the same behavior, whether they're fetching data from a Single, Channel, or Structure.

Comment: Three items...   1) I no longer get an error.  And I can print the `body` field using `{{ notFound.body }}` ...but... 2) The image using `{{ notFound.postImage.first().url}}` does not display, even though it is assigned.   ...and 3) why is it possible to use `{{entry.title}} or `{{ entry.body}}` without defining `entry`  -- and here I am using the crafty brewery or default news channel in Craft.

Comment: Do you have `devMode` enabled? I feel like some of these errors would be more apparent with that on.

Comment: Yes, and there is no error being thrown.

Comment: Strange.  The thumb of the image appears in assets, with the correct file size.  It appears in the entry.  But it was not visible in assets when I tried to "view asset".  I was also unable to "replace file".   It said the file was "empty."  Anyway, I assume that is just a quirk. I deleted the asset and uploaded another copy.  Everything works now.  Many thanks.